# NPM error installing Angular2

Tags: angular, terminal, npm

I have encountered the following errors trying to install Angular2 via Terminal.

I checked Node and NPM and they are up to date.

[Terminal grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSrv4.png)

I'm new to this so any help would be great.

Cheers,

Spen

Comment: Post the error, as text, in the question itself.

Comment: Try removing your node_modules folder, installing Angular2 including it as a dependency (passing --save, -S or -SE flag) and then running npm install again. Also, make sure you're using npm v3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try to fix the problem:

Remove your node_modules folder;
Install Angular2 including it as a dependency to the project by passing --save, -S or -SE flag when installing it, ie.: `$ npm i -S angular2` which is the same as `$ npm install --save angular2`.

Run npm install again.

Make sure you're using npm v3.

If you're using a version of angular2-webpack-starter, update it to the latest version. I checked online and they've been fixing some issues. You may have come [across this one](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/501).

I hope any of this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues when I started with Angular2. Please consider looking into your npm version. I would suggest the following steps for setting up a angular2 project with some dependencies.

1) Try running this command to make sure, you have the latest version of npm :  npm install npm -g

2) Have a package.json like the one below : (This is Angular 2 RC5 version)

```
{
"name": "silk-ui",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "Aswin Gopalan",
"description": "User Interface for SILK",
"scripts": {
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"lite": "lite-server",
"typings": "typings",
"postinstall": "typings install"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.0",
"typescript": "^1.8.10",
"typings": "^0.7.12"
},
"repository": {}
}
```

Setting dependencies in the right order is also very important to make sure all packages are installed correctly.

Hope this helps !

Comment: That's great Aswin, thanks.

Everything seems to work except I now get the following error:



`angular/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(1,10): error TS2661: Cannot re-export name that is not defined in the module.`



I wonder if this is related to the ordering you mention?

Comment: Hey ! What version of angular2 are you using ? 
If you are using TypeScript version : 1.8.10, you'll need  angular2 beta.7 or higher. Hope this helps !